# CSS media query, target only screens larger than phone

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm trying to make a css media query that will only kick in for screen larger than an iphone and my googling has not solved it.

So I want my media query to target only devices tablet size and up. Smartphones should not be targeted.

This is what I've tried:

```
    @media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 1136px) and (min-width:561px)
```

but it seems to not work for my iphone 5; the phone still executes the css in the query.

Comment: Did you remember the <viewport> tag in your html?

Comment: No I didn't remember that. Will it fail without?

Comment: Well, on a mobile device, websites that aren't optimized for mobile are zoomed-out by default so you can see the whole thing. So 1px in your CSS doesn't equal 1 actual pixel of your screen width. To fix this, use the viewport. Something like: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
@media (min-width:641px)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Even when I use `min-width: 769px` both iphone 4 and 5 use the css

Comment: ooh, I think varnish cache on my server is preventing the changes I make from going through straight away - your method may yet work!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this solution help You. This's for iPhone 4.

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```